# Exchange 2013 MailboxQuarantineMonitor AlertValue repairing

Tags: exchange-2013

When I run a Get-Serverhealth on our Exchange 2013 server I get this message:

```
Server          State           Name                 TargetResource       HealthSetName   AlertValue ServerComponent

myserver    NotApplicable   MailboxQuarantine... Mailbox Database ... Store           Repairing  None
```

The repairing state is there for more than a week now and I dont know how to fix it.

The server is running on Windows Server 2012 R, Exchange 2013 build 1178.4

I didn't find naything on this error, so any clue will be appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from another forum. I found that one mailbox was on Quarantine.

I got an answer there:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1947792-exchange-quanramtine-mailbox-is-repairing

Thank you

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers to prevent link rot. Instead, add the most relevant information from the link to your answer or alternatively, post the link as a comment instead of an answer. See [this](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) help center article for further information.